# Entire functions and their characteristics

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

Let $O\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open and $f:O\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function. Further let $a>0$ and $x\in O$ be such that $\overline{U_a(x)}$ is completely contained in $O$.

> 1 How do I show that $|\frac{d^k}{dz^k}f(x)|\leq\sup_{z\in\overline{U_a(x)}}|f(z)|\frac{k!}{a^k}$?
>   2 Let $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function such that $|g(z)|\leq A |z|^k$ for all $|z|>1$ and a constant $A$. How do I show that $g$ must be a polynomial in $z$ with degree $k$ or less?

What I know:
1 I was thinking maybe to use Cauchy generalized integral formula, but I wouldn't know how, or if I should at all.
2 My only idea here was to use the result from 1, but more than that I could not think of.
I would greatly apreciate any nudges in the right direction!

Comment: Q2 is a duplicate on this site. A search should turn it up along with the A. I dk whether it is named after anybody.

Comment: @user254665 Of what is it a duplicate?

Comment: If $g is entire and $|g(z)\leq |f(z)|$ for  a polynomial $ f$, for all $z$ then  prove $g$ is a polynomial. I dk the exact wording of the Q or its #.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For 1, differentiate under the integral in the Cauchy integral formula and then estimate using the M-L inequality. For 2, use 1 and the fact that $a>0$ can be as large as you like.

EDIT: By the Cauchy integral formula, it is not hard to show
$$\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm d^kx}f(x)=\frac{k!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-x|=a}\frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dz$$
Using the M-L inequality, we find
$$\left|\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm d^kx}f(x)\right|\le\frac1{2\pi}\sup_{|z-x|=a}\left|\frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{k+1}}\right|\cdot2\pi a\le ak!\cdot\sup_{z\in\overline{U_a(x)}}\frac{|f(z)|}{a^{k+1}}$$
which is what we want. Now for 2, replace $f$ by $g$ and $k$ by $k+1$. What happens when $a\to\infty$?

Comment: Can you maybe show 1? And for 2 what do you mean by $a$?

Comment: Just edited in 1.

Comment: Thankyou, arent you missing a term $k!$ in the last line? If $a\rightarrow\infty$, then we get 0?

Comment: Yes, well spotted. I've edited.

Comment: Re Q2 .You mean A,not a? Eh?

Comment: No, $A$ is a constant whereas $a$ refers to the radius of the disk $U_a(x)$.

Comment: But what if $a\rightarrow\infty$? Does the expression go to $0$? And why does that imply a polynomial?

Comment: Please see question above

Comment: You should be able to tell me what happens when $a\to\infty$! What kind of function has identically vanishing $(k+1)$th derivatives?